# re.findall - Getting a list of items from a comma delimited string

Tags: python, regex

Let's say you have a string (say a list of Christmas presents).

```
presents = 'iPods, Windows 8, .hack//Sign boxset , red shoes    , Wall-E DVD,  Deus Ex: Human Revolution        '
```

The comma delimited items are all arbitrary and can contains numbers, punctuation, or special characters (except commas). I want to get an array of these items using Python.

```
presents_arr = ['iPods', 'Windows 8', '.hack//Sign boxset', 'red shoes', 'Wall-E DVD', 'Deus Ex: Human Revolution']
```

I would normally do this by splitting the string with the comma delimiter and then cleaning up each string with split.

```
presents = presents.split(',')
presents = [present.strip() for present in presents]
```

Our of curiosity, can I do this specifically with re.findall? I am requiring the same exact behavior as split/strip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct translation would be something like:

```
presents = [x.strip() for x in re.findall(r'[^,]*', presents) if x]
```

An improvement would be to split on whitespace surrounded commas:

```
presents = re.split(r'\s*,\s*', presents)
```

But **please don't** do either of these in this case. There is simply no way to improve upon the clarity of:

```
presents = presents.split(',')
```

and in the case the performance will be worse than the simple split, also.

Answer (score 0):

You could search for `[^,]*`, and it would be equivalent to your split by `,`. However, a better way would be splitting by `\s*,\s*` - that way you don't need the `strip` part, and that is not something you can easily do with `findall`. (Actually, I believe you can't do it at all, due to requirement for variable-length negative lookbehind.)

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall(r'[^,\s]+', presents)
```